# App won't display and crashes in fullscreen

Tags: android, themes, fullscreen, manifest

I'm making an app that I want in fullscreen (well, it can have the icons on top such as signal, battery etc, but no titlebar). It's in landscape and I'm testing on my "ye olde" Samsung Galaxy Ace.

When using the regular android:theme="@style/AppTheme it's fine, but has the titlebar. Whenever I've tried the usual solutions (changing it to a fullscreen, no titlebar style - don't have the code on me) it'll load up, but the screen itself stays blank, until it crashes a few seconds later.

I'll paste the relevant files and logcat...

Manifest...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myname.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity...

```
    package com.example.myname;

import com.example.simpletimer.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;



import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
//            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
//                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
//                    .commit();
//        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Logcat...

```
09-20 20:37:56.890: I/ApplicationPackageManager(15836): cscCountry is not German : BTU
09-20 20:37:56.960: W/dalvikvm(15836): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simpletimer/com.example.myname.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at com.example.myname.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-20 20:37:56.984: E/AndroidRuntime(15836):    ... 11 more
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

**EDIT AND MY ANSWER**

Okay, I tried the two solutions listed below but unfortunately couldn't find a theme that worked, and the posted ones weren't found in my resources. So I put the following code in my MainActivity:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
```

This is just after the

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

I'll still accept both answers below (if I can) as, whilst they did point me in the right direction but I couldn't get them to work (which was my fault), I'm sure they'd help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace if fairly clear about the issue.   You're trying to use a theme that doesn't work with the v7 compatibility library.

You'll need to use a theme that is Theme.AppCompat or a theme derived from Theme.AppCompat.

Or, if you really don't need to extend from ActionBarActivity, you can simply extend from Activity.

More info from another post here:

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: Good advice for others - sadly I couldn't get this working for some reason so I used another solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Logcat says:

> You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this
>   activity.

For example use `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` for this Activity in Manifest

Comment: Good advice for others - sadly I couldn't get this working for some reason so I used another solution.